# How to install Cmake 3.4.1 on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake

I have an Android Studio project that was created using CMake 3.4.1 and I can't get it to compile using the latest CMake (3.6.4). Is there a way I can get CMake 3.4.1 on Android Studio? Please, see the [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttrRo.png).

Comment: Hello and Welcome to SO ! Have a look at this guide : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Do you have any error message ?

Comment: you probably should just install that CMake 3.6.4 package and improve the code. "can't get it to compile" is not an "error description".

Comment: could you fix your CMake scripts to make it workable with 3.6.4? that would be the best.  You could try with "external CMake way": https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code#vanilla_cmake. Basically download and install CMake 3.4.1, and install ninja, make sure both CMake 3.4.1 and Ninja are in PATH, then add version "3.4.1"  in the gradle block having path  ".../your-top-level.CMakelist.txt".

Answer (score 1):

You just download the cmake version 3.4.1.

copy the cmake version 3.4.1 and go to SDK location find cmake folder and paste this file.